# WCF Service error while connecting to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, wcf, sqldatareader

I have written a WCF service which is connecting to a SQL Server 2008 database. I am getting the following error occasionally on stored procedure execution:

> There is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first

Just to point out, I am not using `DataReader`, I am using `SqlDataAdapter` and that to defined as a local variable.

I am calling the dispose method of `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` classes, but still I am getting this error.

Please advise if I am missing something here.

```
  public DataTable executeScalerDT(string sSPName, string[] sParameterNames, string[] sParameterValues, string[] sParameterDataTypes)
    {
        int iReturnCode = 0;
        DataTable oDataTable = null;
        int i = 0;
        try
        {

            SqlCommand oSQLCommand = new SqlCommand(sSPName, oConnection);
            oSQLCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter oSQLParameter = null;
            SqlParameter p_RETURN_CODE = null;


            for (i = 0; i < sParameterNames.Length; i++)
            {
                if (sParameterNames[i] != "@iReturnCode")
                {
                    oSQLParameter = oSQLCommand.Parameters.Add(sParameterNames[i], getDataType(sParameterDataTypes[i]));
                    oSQLParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    oSQLParameter.Value = sParameterValues[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    p_RETURN_CODE = oSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@iReturnCode", getDataType(sParameterDataTypes[i]));
                    p_RETURN_CODE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
            }
            SqlDataAdapter oSqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(oSQLCommand);
            oDataTable = new DataTable();
            oSqlAdapter.Fill(oDataTable);
            oSqlAdapter.Dispose();
            oSQLCommand.Dispose();            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SharedClasses.Logger.Error("[DAL.executeScalerDT] Exception Occurred sSPName:" + sSPName  +" sTemplateCode:" + sTemplateCode  + " ex:" + ex.Message);
        }
        return oDataTable;
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code

Comment: Code updated to the question. Please assist.

Comment: Your problem is with `oConnection` which is not shown. Do you use a shared / centralized connection (which I would advice against 9 times out of 10)? Also some advice, but you should wrap your disposables in the using statements, because you're not disposing correct.

Comment: Hi, oConnection is shared connection and it is obtained from a Connection Pool.  so, once it is served it is being sent again to the pool to serve other request. What I understood if I could put the dispose in the finally block? Moreover, why Data Reader error is coming even when there is no Data Reader used.